# Yii2: How to convert data type value of a JSON PHP array?

Tags: php, json, yii2, type-conversion

I am using Yii2 framework to create this JSON array:

```
"data": [
  {
    "id": 201,
    "name": "John",
    "age": "30"
  }
]
```

The age is a **string** and I need it to be an **integer**, that is, without quotation marks. Like this:

```
"data": [
    {
      "id": 201,
      "name": "John",
      "age": 30
    }
]
```

This is the PHP function that create the JSON array:

```
$persons['data'] = Persons::find()
    ->select([
        'id',
        'name',
        'age'
    ])
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

Comment: can you use Int($age), before make json?

Comment: 1/ Can you change it BEFORE creating the JSON array? 2/ Where do you need it to be an integer and not a string? You can maybe change it juste BEFORE using it too. 3/ If you can't do it in my 1/ or 2/, maybe try some `json_decode($array)`, transform the string in int then `json_encode($array)` to get your array as before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` flag as second parameter of `json_encode()` or `\yii\helpers\Json::encode()` for converting numbers automatically since php 5.3, see [`here`](http://php.net/json_encode).

You can use the flag like

```
$data = Persons::find()
    ->select(
      [
         'id',
         'name',
         'age'
      ]
    )
    ->asArray()
    ->all();

$json = \yii\helpers\Json::encode($data,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK would make name etc also int if Integer is saved in those fields. I am assuming this is in context or rest api. You can override the fields() in your model.

```
public function fields()
{
    $fields = parent::fields();
    $fields['someProperty'] = function ($model) {
        
        return $model->someOtherProperty + something etc;
    };
    return $fields;
}
```