# asArray() in yii2 convert all integer to string

Tags: php, arrays, yii, yii2, frameworks

i used in yii2 framework

in query select after asAarray() but in response json all integer to string !

```
$users = $model->asArray()->limit($limit)->offset($offset)->all();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yii2: How to convert data type value of a JSON PHP array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51770766/yii2-how-to-convert-data-type-value-of-a-json-php-array)

Answer (score -1):

`asArray()`
Whether to return the query results in terms of arrays instead of Active Records.

so it won't change your integer data, `json_encode()` or use `yii\web\Response->format = 'json'` to return json data may be used for you.